# Randomize arguments ( that hold color codes) from an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, random

I have the array (shown below) with arguments that hold color codes.

The intended purpose of my script is to randomize those arguments when the user inputs

```
scriptname randoms Text
```

so that every time it will display the `Text` on the screen in a different color.

Below I wrote some if statements not related to this particular problem, they work when I tested them. The problem I have is with randomizing colours when the user inputs

```
scriptname randoms Text
```

Here is the script:

```
#!\bin\bash
declare -A colours=(
[black]="0;30" [red]="0;31" [green]="0;32" [yellow]="0;33" [blue]="0;34" [magenta]="0;35" [cyan]="0;36" [white]="0;37"
[BLACK]="1;30" [RED]="1;31" [GREEN]="1;32" [YELLOW]="1;33" [BLUE]="1;34" [MAGENTA]="1;35" [CYAN]="1;36" [WHITE]="1;37"
[bLaCk]="0;30" [rEd]="0;31" [gReEn]="0;32" [yElLoW]="0;33" [bLuE]="0;34" [mAgEnTa]="0;35" [cYaN]="0;36" [wHiTe]="0;37"
[BlAcK]="1;30" [ReD]="1;31" [GrEeN]="1;32" [YeLlOW]="1;33" [BlUe]="1;34" [MaGeNtA]="1;35" [CyAn]="1;36" [WhItE]="1;37")

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo Usage: echoc COLOUR STRING
        exit 1
fi
regex='^black$|^red$|^green$|^yellow$|^blue$|^magenta$|^cyan$|^white$'
randoms=$(( $RANDOM % $regex )); echo $randoms
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ $1 =~ $randoms ]] ; then
        echo -ne '\e['${colours[$randoms]}m
        shift
        echo -e $*'\e[0m'
        exit 2
        fi
```

Comment: I don't understand the command line arguments: you want the user to enter a valid colour, then you print the next argument in a random colour. Is that right?

Comment: Note that your slashes are backwards: should be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: lets say the script name is showc i want when user type in showc random helloo. script print out hello from the random color pool.

Comment: You want the user to type the word "random"?

Comment: yes i want user type the word random after script name.some thing like showc random hello. then terminal display "hello" in random color.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand how you want your script to work. I rewrote it a bit: print out all the command line arguments, each letter in a random colour:

```
#!/bin/bash

#     [black]=30
#     [red]=31
#     [green]=32
#     [yellow]=33
#     [blue]=34
#     [magenta]=35
#     [cyan]=36
#     [white]=37
function random_colour {
    local bold=$(( $RANDOM % 2 ))
    local code=$(( 30 + $RANDOM % 8 ))
    printf "%d;%d\n" $bold $code
}

sentence="$*"
for (( i=0; i<${#sentence}; i++ )); do
    printf "\e[%sm%c" "$(random_colour)" "${sentence:i:1}"
done
echo -e '\e[0m'
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/terminfo
text='some text'
b=(%B '')
print -rP -- ${text//(#m)?/%F{$((RANDOM%terminfo[colors]))}$b[RANDOM%2+1]${MATCH//\%/%%}}%b%f
```